# Hexadecimal Representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the last digit of the hexadecimal representation of the number
(in decimal notation)
$$1+10+10^2+10^3+\cdots+10^{100}$$

I calculated the sum of the series above using GP and obtained $\frac{10^{101}-1}{9}$ but i don't know how to continue from here onwards.

Please help!

Comment: $1 + 10 + 10^2 + \dots + 10^{100}$ is a positive number, but $\frac{10^{101}-1}{-9}$ is negative. You should have $\frac{1 - 10^{101}}{-9}$, which is equivalent to $\frac{10^{101}-1}{9}$.

Comment: How do you find the last digit of a number $N$ in base $10$?  (What computation yields the last digit?)  "Look at it" is not a computation.

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer 7, here are the details.

You may disregard all summands starting with $10^4$ and after, since they are all divisible by 16. (The last digit of $10^k$ in base $16$ is $0$ as long as $k\ge 4$.) So it is enough to look at $1+10+100+1000=1111$ and then take $1111 \mod 16 = 7$. You could even do this without a calculator if you remember that $32^2=1024$, so $1111 - 1024 \mod 16 = 11 + 1100 - 1024 = 11+76 = 87 = 7 \mod 16$.

Comment: Great, got it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

for $n \ge 4$ we have $16 | 10^n$

so the answer must be $1111 (\mod 16)$, which is $7$